# time between events by customer id using pandas

Tags: pandas

for the sample data below, I'd like to compute the mean time delta *gap* between events, grouped by customer id.

what's the best way to achieve this in pandas?

```
CUSTOMER_ID,    ORDER_AT
1,  2020-11-11 23:30:13
1,  2020-11-11 23:32:53
1,  2020-11-11 23:34:44
1,  2020-11-11 23:35:55
2,  2020-11-11 23:37:54
2,  2020-11-11 23:39:23
3,  2020-11-09 23:59:46
3,  2020-11-10 0:03:04
3,  2020-11-10 0:05:35
3,  2020-11-10 0:19:40
3,  2020-11-11 2:48:17
3,  2020-11-11 2:49:06
3,  2020-11-11 2:50:39
3,  2020-11-11 2:51:57
4,  2020-11-14 1:12:52
4,  2020-11-14 1:13:14
4,  2020-11-14 16:56:18
```

Comment: what is you expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').ORDER_AT.agg(lambda x: x.diff().mean())
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER_ID
1             0 days 00:01:54
2             0 days 00:01:29
3   0 days 03:50:18.714285714
4             0 days 07:51:43
```

If you need the time delta as a number, e.g. as minutes, use `x.diff().mean().seconds/60`